# IDA PRO decompiler expression last question (pseudocode)

Tags: ida, decompiler, pointer

```
memory=VirtualAlloc(lpAddress, 3*v48, flAllocationType, 16*v19);

                 .....

shellcode=(int (__stdcall *)(_DWORD, _DWORD))memory;

                 .....

shellcode(&hkernel32, 0)
```

If function pointer, for each parameter `(_DWORD, _DWORD)` is

`lpAddress = _DWORD = &hkernel32`

`flAllocationType = _DWORD=0`

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
memory=VirtualAlloc(lpAddress, 3*v48, flAllocationType, 16*v19);
```

memory will hold the allocated address

```
(int (__stdcall *)(_DWORD, _DWORD))
```

prototype of a function that takes two arguments of type DWORD  (can be anything ida cannot know it arbitrarily chose DWORD based on size of parameter )

```
so  this line
```

shellcode=(int (__stdcall *)(_DWORD, _DWORD))memory;

means

shellcode = memory

the next call is calling this addresss by trreating this address as a function pointer

so if you single step this line you will land on the allocated address

and execute shell code

it has nothing to do with flwhatever or &hkernel

from the looks of it it is a shell code that takes the base of kernel and tries to scan some thing in the shell code

Answer (score 0):

It means that memory is treated as a function pointer, of a function with `stdcall` calling conventions, that receives 2 arguments and returns `int` value.

Comment: Thanks and I've one question.